# Getting black graph when using Matplotlib in my Python notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm testing different visualization tools from my python Jupyter Notebook, based on the following blog post comparison http://pbpython.com/visualization-tools-1.html

First, I import libraries and check versions:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

print "Pandas version: " + pd.__version__
print "Matplotlib version: " + matplotlib.__version__
```

Which prints:

```
Pandas version: 0.17.1
Matplotlib version: 1.5.1
```

Then, I load the data from the CSV file (located at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2439854/tmp/mn-budget-detail-2014.csv):

```
budget_full = pd.read_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2439854/tmp/mn-budget-detail-2014.csv')
budget = budget_full.sort_values(by = 'amount', ascending = False)[:10]
```

Finally, I plot the data:

```
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

budget_plot = budget.plot(kind = "bar", x = budget["detail"],
                      title = "MN Capital Budget - 2014",
                      legend = False)
```

Unfortunately, this produces a little black figure

[image]

My Python version is:

```
Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

I'm on a Mac OSX (El Capitan) and I'm managing my python environment using Anaconda Continuum Analytics.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ... why on earth are you linking to a dropbox file instead of including the image in the question? Use the button at the right of `{}` to insert an image. If the image is too big you can change the URL by adding an `s` at the end to obtain a small imag (`m` for medium) (e.g. `.../123456.png` becomes `.../123456s.png`)

Comment: Have you tried inlining your figures in Jupyter using `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: Thanks Jens, you're right. I forgot to add `%matplotlib inline`, and it works now. Thanks also for the edit. Can you add this comment as an answer so I can validate it?

Comment: I'm glad that this worked for you. Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried inlining your figures in Jupyter using `%matplotlib inline`?